# Why is time harmonic follow the form of $e^{-i\omega t}$, not $e^{i\omega t}$?

Tags: wavefunction, conventions, notation, complex-numbers, harmonics

In physics, when we solve an PDE or ODE, the solution usually has the form of
\begin{equation}
f=C_+e^{i\lambda x}+C_-e^{-i\lambda x}
\end{equation}
and the "causility" will eliminate one term as it violates the "physics".
I am wondering how the "causility" is defined here. In detail, I will focus on the time harmonic term as it directly reflects the "causility".
As for time harmonic, the harmonic term usually takes the form
\begin{equation}
T(t)\sim e^{-i\omega t}
\end{equation}
However, in some books or papers, there seems to be another set of notations, they replace the imaginary unit $i$ with $-j$, which reads
\begin{equation}
T(t)\sim e^{j\omega t}
\end{equation}
I've heard some explanations on this topic like:

1. Both $i$ and $j$ are square roots of $-1$, but "$i$" is "$+\sqrt{-1}$" while "$j$" stands for "$-\sqrt{-1}$".
2. In engineering, especially electronic engineering, "$i(t)$" is preseved as the transient current. So those people will use "$j$" as the imaginary unit.

Both notion sets actually work for me. However, during review tasks, I saw a few (very few) papers were parepared with notation
\begin{equation}
T(t)\sim e^{i\omega t}
\end{equation}
With this notion set, the harmonic phase development will be quite confusing, the phase term can be any combination of:
\begin{equation}
\pm kr \pm \omega t
\end{equation}

Here, my question is:
Why is time harmonic term $e^{-i\omega t}$ rather than $e^{i\omega t}$, is there any reason for this or is it idiomatic since the first guy (who's that guy?)

Comment: Hi Tippsie. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please only ask 1 question per post.

Comment: Thanks Qmechanic, just removed the 2nd question.

Comment: "I am wondering how the 'causility' [sic] is defined here." Causality generally means that the past affects the future, and not vice versa. I kick a dog, the dog yelps. My action (kick) caused the dog's response (yelp). The "Caus-" part of "causality" comes from the word "cause."

Comment: What book uses $j=-\sqrt{-1}$?

Answer (score 3):

1. $j$ is the engineering notation.  There is no difference except in notation between $e^{i\omega t}$ and $e^{j\omega t}$.
2. what matters is the relative phase.  $kx-\omega t$ or $-kx+\omega t$ both describe waves moving toward the $+x$ direction, whereas $kx+\omega t$ describes a wave moving in the $-x$ direction.  The rest is convention, which may be different in different textbook.  I’m a little more used to $kx-\omega t$ because the point of phasors is to remove the explicit time-dependence and it $e^{ikx}$ avoids using a $-$ sign all the time.

Comment: Thanks ZeroTheHere, but I would argue $e^{-i\omega t}$ is identical with $e^{j\omega t}$, i.e. $i=-j$

Comment: @Tippsie I have no idea why you would think this, and I’ve never seen this in use in 20 years of teaching E&M to engineers.

Comment: I first heard that as a joke in an undergrad lecture. "You know, the electrical engineers chose the **other** root of $\sqrt{-1}$ and called it $j$." [Stares out the window pensively.] "Sometimes I worry that we chose the wrong root and they chose the right root."

Answer (score 1):

assume you want to solve this ODE

$$\ddot x+\omega^2\,x=0$$

you make the Ansatz $~x(t)=A\,\rm e^{\lambda\,t}$ and obtain

$$\underbrace{A\,\rm e^{\lambda\,t}}_{\ne 0}\,\left(\lambda^2+\omega^2\right)=0$$
from here $~\lambda=\pm i\,\omega~$
thus our solution is

$$x(t)=A\rm e^{+i\omega\,t}\quad,A\rm e^{-i\omega\,t}$$
or because we have linear ODE, the superposition of both solution
$$x(t)=A\rm e^{+i\omega\,t}+B \rm e^{-i\omega\,t}$$